# Why do I get Error: No module named 'gspread' on AWS Lambda when I've tried adding as a layer and adding to requirements.txt?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, gspread

I installed the following modules in a directory, zipped them, added them as layers to my lambda function:  
google-api-python-client version 2.73.0
gpread version 5.7.2
boto3
Google-auth 2.16.0

ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'a': No module named 'gspread'
Traceback (most recent call last)

Here is my code:

import io
import json
import csv
import boto3
import gspread
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

def b(event, context):
# Get the S3 event data
s3_event = event["Records"][0]["s3"]
bucket_name = s3_event["bucket"]["name"]
file_name = s3_event["object"]["key"]

```
# Connect to S3 and get the CSV file data
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
csv_data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)["Body"].read().decode()


# Convert the CSV data to a list
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_data.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
csv_list = list(csv_reader)

# Authenticate with Google Sheets API using service account credentials
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('/credentials.json')
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
# Connect to the sheet
sheet_id = 'redacted'
sh = gc.open_by_key(sheet_id)
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

# Clear the current data
worksheet.clear()

# Insert the new data
cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:' + gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(len(csv_list), len(csv_list[0])))
for i, val in enumerate(sum(csv_list, [])):
    cell_list[i].value = val
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Data inserted successfully')
}
```

I have installed all the required dependencies, yet but I'm still getting module can't be found. This has been a problem with most of the dependencies I've installed, yet for some reason boto3 worked when I added it to requirements.txt

here is my requirements.txt contents:

gspread
google-auth
google-auth-oauthlib
google-auth-httplib2

Answer (score 0):

boto3 is part of lambda runtime. No need to install it. But be careful as lambda might not include the [latest version of boto3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html). If you want the latest version of boto3, you have to package it as well.

For your problem, I suggest you follow this. Never had any issue with that:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/blank-python

The problem is that you are probably not packaging your dependency into a python folder.

This link is also useful:

https://shubhamshivhare.medium.com/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-df2af133a1d1